# Limits and intermediate value theorem

Tags: calculus

Assume that a continuous function $f$ : $]1, 2[ \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ satisfies
$$\lim_{x \to 1^+} f(x) = -\infty \text{ and } \lim_{x \to 2^-} f(x) = -\infty $$

Show that there exists an, $c ∈]1, 2[$, for which all $x \in ]1, 2[$ $f(x) \leq f(c)$

What's the mathematical way to show this and intuition behind this? We're supposed to show this by the intermediate value theorem right?

Comment: This statement looks wrong to me. This would imply that $f$ is bounded in the neighbourhood of 1

Comment: Forgot the negative sign. Updated.

Comment: From the two limits there is $1/2>\delta>0$ such that for $x<1+\delta$ and $x>2-\delta$ one has $f(x)<f(3/2)$. Since $f$ is continuous on $[1+\delta,2-\delta]$ there is a $c\in[1+\delta,2-\delta]$ such that for all $x\in[1+\delta,2-\delta]$ one has $f(x)\leq f(c)$. But $3/2\in[1+\delta,2-\delta]$ therefore $f(c)\geq f(3/2)$. So, $f(c)\geq f(x)$ for all $x\in]1,2[$.

Comment: Have you seen something like: a continuous function on a closed bounded interval $[a,b]$ attains its maximum? If so, can you build on that to prove your statement?

Comment: Do you mean Weierstrass theorem?

Comment: I didn't know it was called Weierstrass, but apparently it is: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extreme_value_theorem